# Placeholder for additional fields with Data.Aeson

Tags: haskell, aeson

Let's say I get a JSON with some fields I know and some fields I don't know:

```
{
  "a": { ... },
  "b": { ... },
  "c": { ... },
  "something": "else",
  "more": {"of": ["the", "same"]},
  "and": ["even", "some", "more"]
}
```

Since the JSON structure is kind of complicated, I would really like to work with it within Haskell using the following data:

```
data A = ...
data B = ...
data C = ...
data MyObject = MyObject
  {
    a :: A
  , b :: B
  , c :: C
  , additionalFields :: Object
  }
```

Is it possible to have the fields a, b and c translated to Haskell objects and all the additional fields be packed and passed as an Aeson.Object?

Also, I don't have any guarantee of the JSON fields order.

Comment: why don't you just use those you know about?

Comment: I would, if I could. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure - just store the Object in additionalFields (the fourth slot):

```
instance FromJSON MyObject where
    parseJSON obj@(Object v) = MyObject  <$>
        v .: "a"                         <*>
        v .: "b"                         <*>
        v .: "c"                         <*>
        (pure obj)
    parseJSON _                      = mzero
```

If you want to remove the keys for `a`, `b` and `c` first, then use:

```
import Data.HashMap.Strict as HM

...

   pure ( HM.delete "a" $ HM.delete "b" $ HM.delete "c" obj )
```